# Where is this VFR reporting point ("Water Tank" near Thousand Oaks, CA) in real life?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, visual-flight-rules

I was looking at the VFR sectional near Thousand Oaks, California. The chart has a "WATER TANK" labeled, but I see many water tanks in Thousand Oaks on the Google Maps satellite view.

Does anyone know which water tank they are referring to on the sectional? And why would they choose something so easily confused with other "water tanks"?

[image: VFR Sectional for Thousand Oaks, CA]
([skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/?ll=34.18572550249198,-118.76707251350523&chart=114&zoom=3))

Comment: Google seems to match VPLWT with some coordinate. Does it match any actual water tank?

Answer (score 6):

The tank is west of Oak Park (Oak Park Canyon), but there is some conflicting information about the exact coordinates of VPLWT.

From [FAA JO 7350.8P](http://tfmlearning.faa.gov/publications/atpubs/lid/L_PV.htm):

> 34-10-49.0000N 118-46-16.0000W.

Converted into decimal degrees: 34.18028°N 118.7711°W

[image: Google Maps at this place]
[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B010'49.0%22N+118%C2%B046'16.0%22W/@34.187991,-118.7799155,204a,35y,39.33t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.18028!4d-118.7711)

Obviously no tank here!

As [@ymb](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/14897/ymb1) pointed out, this document has been cancelled, and in the [current version (JO 7350.9N)](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/LID_7350.9N_11-8-18.pdf), the coordinates have changed:

> 34-11-01.0000N 118-46-41.0000W.

Converted into decimal degrees: 34.18361°N 118.7781°W

[image]
[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B011'01.0%22N+118%C2%B046'41.2%22W/@34.18361,-118.7802887,786m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.1836111!4d-118.7781111)

An underground tank, well visible from the sky. The tank itself is likely similar to this (it may be it, but not sure):

[image]
<sup>"Local officials recently toured and inspected the new Oak Canyon water tank under construction in Oak Park", [source](https://www.toacorn.com/articles/new-manager-to-oversee-operations-at-triunfo-sanitation-district/)</sup>

**Other tanks**

There are also two external tanks in the neighborhood, but none corresponds to FAA coordinates, e.g. this one:

[image]
<sup>[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B010'49.0%22N+118%C2%B046'16.0%22W/@34.187991,-118.7799155,204a,35y,39.33t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.18028!4d-118.7711)</sup>

which is a bit north of the underground tank. Overall picture:

[image]
<sup>[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B010'49.0%22N+118%C2%B046'16.0%22W/@34.1832292,-118.7909189,2928m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.18028!4d-118.7711)</sup>

It seems FAA has not done a good job about this waypoint identification. While the current source identifies a tank, it should be mentioned this tank is underground, as this makes a difference.